# Realation between direct sum and Cartesian product

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, geometry

Let $X_1, X_2$ be such that $X_1 = A_1\oplus B_1$ and $X_2 = A_2\oplus B_2$.
What happens if I consider the Cartesian product $X_1\times X_2$?
Could I write
$$X_1\times X_2 = A\oplus B?$$
There exist some relations between $A, A_1, A_2$ and $B, B_1, B_2$?
Could anyone please help or give some references?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You could say that $X_1 \times X_2 \cong (A_1 \times A_2) \oplus (B_1 \times B_2)$ is an isomorphism of vector spaces, but it wouldn't be correct to say that these spaces are "equal" in the conventional sense

Comment: @BenGrossmann thank you. Could you give me a reference?

Comment: No, but I could probably write a proof. What definition are you using for $\oplus$, exactly? (In particular, is $\oplus$ an "internal" or "external" direct sum?)

Comment: It is an internal direct sum.

Comment: In that case, equality does make sense! I'll write something up

Comment: What do you mean with your last comment? Could you please explain me?

Comment: For sets $A,B,C,D$ (and also for vector spaces), we have $(A \times B) \cap (C \times D) = (A \cap C) \times (B \cap D)$. Does that clear anything up? Is this what you want clarified?

Comment: Yes, perfectly, thank you @BenGrossmann.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $X_1 \times X_2 \cong (A_1 \times A_2) \oplus (B_1 \times B_2)$. To prove this, it suffices to show that each element $x \in X_1 \times X_2$ can be written in the form $v_1 + v_2$ with $v_1 \in A_1 \times A_2$ and $v_2 \in B_1 \times B_2$, and that $(A_1 \times A_2 )\cap(B_1 \times B_2) = \{0\}$.

Indeed, by the definition of the Cartesian product we have $x = (x_1,x_2)$ for $x_1 \in X_1,x_2 \in X_2$. It follows that $x_1 = a_1 + b_1$ and $x_2 = a_2 + b_2$ with $a_i \in A_i$ and $b_i \in B_i$, so that
$$
x = (x_1,x_2) = (a_1,b_1) + (a_2,b_2).
$$
For the second part, we note that
$$
(A_1 \times A_2 )\cap(B_1 \times B_2) = (A_1 \cap B_1) \times (A_2 \cap B_2) = \{0\}\times\{0\} = \{0\}.
$$